# How to split the column with same delimiter

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

My dataframe is this and I want to split my data frame by colon (`:`)

```
+------------------+
|Name:Roll_no:Class|
+------------------+
|      #ab:cd#:23:C|
|      #sd:ps#:34:A|
|      #ra:kh#:14:H|
|      #ku:pa#:36:S|
|      #ra:sh#:50:P|
+------------------+
```

and I want my dataframe like:

```
+-----+-------+-----+
| Name|Roll_no|Class|
+-----+-------+-----+
|ab:cd|     23|    C|
|sd:ps|     34|    A|
|ra:kh|     14|    H|
|ku:pa|     36|    S|
|ra:sh|     50|    P|
+-----+-------+-----+
```

Comment: have you tried using `sep=':'` during `read_csv`

Comment: yes it will split name too

Comment: Are you asking for pandas or pyspark?

Answer (score 5):

If need split by last 2 `:` use [`Series.str.rsplit`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.rsplit.html), then set columns by split column name and last remove first and last `#` by indexing:

```
col = 'Name:Roll_no:Class'
df1 = df[col].str.rsplit(':', n=2, expand=True)
df1.columns = col.split(':')
df1['Name'] = df1['Name'].str[1:-1]
#if only first and last value
#df1['Name'] = df1['Name'].str.strip('#')
print (df1)
    Name Roll_no Class
0  ab:cd      23     C
1  sd:ps      34     A
2  ra:kh      14     H
3  ku:pa      36     S
4  ra:sh      50     P
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [read_csv()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) **sep=':'** and **quotechar='#'**

```
str = """Name:Roll_no:Class 
#ab:cd#:23:C 
#sd:ps#:34:A 
#ra:kh#:14:H 
#ku:pa#:36:S 
#ra:sh#:50:P"""

df = pd.read_csv(pd.io.common.StringIO(str), sep=':', quotechar='#')
>>> df
     Name  Roll_no Class
#0  ab:cd       23     C
#1  sd:ps       34     A
#2  ra:kh       14     H
#3  ku:pa       36     S
#4  ra:sh       50     P
```

Comment: @CoolTriks for pyspark, you can do the similar: `df = spark.read.csv('/file/path', quote='#', sep=':', header=True)`. Or for existing field, use two functions.split() (first by '#' and then by ':') to retrieve needed fields.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you could do this in pyspark:

**Specify the separator and the quote on read**

If you're reading the data from a file, you can use `spark.read_csv` with the following arguments:

```python
df = spark.read.csv("path/to/file", sep=":", quote="#", header=True)
df.show()
#+-----+-------+-----+
#| Name|Roll_no|Class|
#+-----+-------+-----+
#|ab:cd|     23|    C|
#|sd:ps|     34|    A|
#|ra:kh|     14|    H|
#|ku:pa|     36|    S|
#|ra:sh|     50|    P|
#+-----+-------+-----+
```

**Use Regular Expressions**

If you're unable to change the way the data is read and you're starting with the DataFrame shown in the question, you can use regular expressions to get the desired output.

First get the new column names by splitting the existing column name on `":"`

```python
new_columns = df.columns[0].split(":")
print(new_columns)
#['Name', 'Roll_no', 'Class']
```

For the `Name` column you need to extract the data between the `#`s. For the other two columns, you need to remove the strings between the `#`s (and the following `":"`) and use `pyspark.sql.functions.split` to extract the components

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import regexp_extract, regexp_replace, split

df.withColumn(new_columns[0], regexp_extract(df.columns[0], r"(?<=#).+(?=#)", 0))\
    .withColumn(new_columns[1], split(regexp_replace(df.columns[0], "#.+#:", ""), ":")[0])\
    .withColumn(new_columns[2], split(regexp_replace(df.columns[0], "#.+#:", ""), ":")[1])\
    .select(*new_columns)\
    .show()
#+-----+-------+-----+
#| Name|Roll_no|Class|
#+-----+-------+-----+
#|ab:cd|     23|    C|
#|sd:ps|     34|    A|
#|ra:kh|     14|    H|
#|ku:pa|     36|    S|
#|ra:sh|     50|    P|
#+-----+-------+-----+
```